# Manipulating two different rows

Tags: sql, if-statement, plsql, count

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT   TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) AS PERIOD,
         QUEUE,
         ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN BESVARET_25_SEK > 0 THEN BESVARET_25_SEK END ) / SUM(CASE WHEN ANTAL_KALD > 0 THEN ANTAL_KALD END) * 100) AS SVAR_PROCENT
FROM     KS_DRIFT.PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT
WHERE    TIDSPUNKT >= '2013-06-17'
AND      TIDSPUNKT <= '2013-07-02'
AND      ANTAL_KALD > 0
AND QUEUE not in ('TekniskHotline')
GROUP BY TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT), QUEUE
ORDER BY PERIOD
```

This gives me the following result:

[image: SQL RESULT]

As you can see i have highlighed two rows. in the above SQL statement im calculating two rows to get a percentage now here is the tricky part and my question instead of having "Erhverv" and "ErhvervOverflow" on a row i want to count them as one!

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What about "Kunder" and "NykreditKunder"? Should they be grouped together as well? If not, would a `GROUP BY TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT), LEFT(QUEUE, 6)` solve the problem or are you looking for a more serious/reliable answer? And what RDBMS is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement to assign the values *both* in the `select` and the `group by`:

```
SELECT   TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT) AS PERIOD,
         (case when QUEUE in ('Erhverv', 'ErhvervOverflow') then 'Erhverv'
               else QUEUE
          end) as QUEUE,
         ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN BESVARET_25_SEK > 0 THEN BESVARET_25_SEK END ) / SUM(CASE WHEN ANTAL_KALD > 0 THEN ANTAL_KALD END) * 100) AS SVAR_PROCENT
FROM     KS_DRIFT.PERO_NKM_KØ_OVERSIGT
WHERE    TIDSPUNKT >= '2013-06-17'
AND      TIDSPUNKT <= '2013-07-02'
AND      ANTAL_KALD > 0
AND QUEUE not in ('TekniskHotline')
GROUP BY TRUNC(TIDSPUNKT),
         (case when QUEUE in ('Erhverv', 'ErhvervOverflow') then 'Erhverv'
               else QUEUE
          end)
ORDER BY PERIOD;
```

Note that I included both values in the `when` clause.  You could do:  `when QUEUE = 'ErhvervOverflow' then 'Erhverv' else QUEUE end)`.  I think including both values makes the intention more clear.